# Special character in AFN parameter causes Access Error

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
NSString *_str=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"28:76:CD:01:45:AE"];
AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
NSDictionary *parameter = @{@"uin" :_str ,
                            @"type" : @"2"
                            };

[manager GET:@"http://www.baidu.com" parameters:parameter success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"~~~~~~~~~%@", task.currentRequest.URL);
} failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {
    NSLog(@"~~~~~~~~~%@", task.currentRequest.URL);
}];
```

The code print as blow:
~~~~~~~~~http://www.baidu.com/?type=2&uin=28%3A76%3ACD%3A01%3A45%3AAE

I solve this problem by write parameter in url:

```
    [manager GET:@"http://www.baidu.com?uin=28:76:CD:01:45:AE&type=2" parameters:parameter success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject) {
      NSLog(@"~~~~~~~~~%@", task.currentRequest.URL);
  } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {
      // print: ~~~~~~~~~http://www.google.com/?type=2&uin=28:76:CD:01:45:AE
      NSLog(@"~~~~~~~~~%@", task.currentRequest.URL);
  }];
```

I do not think this is a good way, Is there a better solution？

Answer (score 0):

this is one of the method :

Store that value in one `String`

```
_str=[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"28:76:CD:01:45:AE"];
```

and then:

```
AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
NSDictionary *parameter = @{@"uin" :_str ,

                            @"type" : @"2"
                           };

[manager GET:@"http://www.google.com" parameters:parameter success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject) {
      NSLog(@"~~~~~~~~~%@", task.currentRequest.URL);
  } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {
      // print: ~~~~~~~~~http://www.google.com/?type=2&uin=28%3A76%3ACD%3A01%3A45%3AAE
      NSLog(@"~~~~~~~~~%@", task.currentRequest.URL);
  }];
```

Comment: I haveTested it, and no effect

Comment: I edit the problem with  Suraj Sukale's method, and it does not work